# How to enable login as in salesforce

Tags: apex

I know that from login policies we can enable this , but i cannot see any option in Login Access Policies.[image]

Comment: is login button available on user's record?

Comment: No its not available there also.

Comment: which edition org you are using? Professional Edition ?

Comment: @Ratan Enterprise

Comment: is your org upgraded from Professional Edition into Enterprise edition ?

Comment: Yes.They just switched from Professional to Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently **Login as Any User** feature is not available for Professional Edition..

If you want this feature in Professional Edition.. Please vote this [**idea exchange post**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ip96AAA)

currently only available to Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Editions.

> when an organization has been upgraded from Professional Edition into
>   Enterprise edition, this feature will need to be manually enabled by
>   support. Please create a case to request it.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User